# Flot chart ignores jquery selector and does not display

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I am trying to create a chart using Flot-chart js i am using ajax to collect the data and after the loop the `d1[]` looks like this:

```
[[0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 1], [5, 1]]
```

Here is my full javascript:

```
    var monthNames = ["Man", "Tir", "Ons", "Tors", "Fre", "Lør", "Søn"];
var d1 = [];
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    module_activity();

});

function module_activity()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Statistic/activity_stats',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            request: 'ajax'
        },
        success: function (data)
        {
            if(data.length > 0)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i += 1) {
                    d1.push([i, parseInt((data[i]['completed_modules']))]);
                }
                $("#flot-1ine8").length && $.plot($("#flot-1ine8"), [{
                    data: d1
                }],
                    {
                        series: {
                            lines: {
                                show: true,
                                lineWidth: 2,
                                fill: true,
                                fillColor: {
                                    colors: [{
                                        opacity: 0.0
                                    }, {
                                        opacity: 0.2
                                    }]
                                }
                            },
                            points: {
                                radius: 5,
                                show: true
                            },
                            grow: {
                                active: true,
                                steps: 50
                            },
                            shadowSize: 2
                        },
                        grid: {
                            hoverable: true,
                            clickable: true,
                            tickColor: "#f0f0f0",
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            color: '#f0f0f0'
                        },
                        colors: ["#65bd77"],
                        xaxis:{
                        },
                        yaxis: {
                            ticks: 1
                        },
                        tooltip: true,
                        tooltipOpts: {
                            content: "chart: %x.1 is %y.4",
                            defaultTheme: false,
                            shifts: {
                                x: 0,
                                y: 20
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );
           }
        }
    });
}
```

When this runs i get no chart visible and i get no errors in the console.

has anyone ever experianced this before and know what i can do to fix it?